# SSH Expired on GCP VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a vm instance which connects to the external ip with http but not with https.
On checking the logs, it shows that the following error:

---

> Invalid ssh key entry - expired key: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDJdFE+rHGtkgTx0niNZRTQYb...........
> ......jH8ycULWLplemekTGdFnwoGhNb google-ssh {"userName":"my_user_name@gmail.com","expireOn":"2022-12-06T17:04:46+0000"}

---

Does anyone know why is this happening or how to resolve this? I have spent at least 10 hrs trying to resolve this issue but I have been unsuccessful as I am not from a technical field.

I tried

- creating a new ssh key - firstly I had never done that - and then updating it in the meta data or through the console terminal etc.
- I tried adding a new ssh key directly too but that didn't work

---

Edit
Ran the following as per the comment:

```
    gcloud compute project-info describe --format flattened
```

Result below:

```
commonInstanceMetadata.fingerprint:    mgT7F7wYfBw=
commonInstanceMetadata.items[0].key:   ssh-keys
commonInstanceMetadata.items[0].value: himanshusomani007:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQA..........cULWLplemekTGdFnwoGhNb google-ssh {"userName":"my_user_name@gmail.com","expireOn":"2023-12-04T17:04:46+0000"}
commonInstanceMetadata.kind:           compute#metadata
creationTimestamp:                     2022-11-17T00:15:29.195-08:00
defaultNetworkTier:                    PREMIUM
defaultServiceAccount:                 1054284009344-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
id:                                    3401782412795466575
kind:                                  compute#project
name:                                  principal-storm-368908
quotas[0].limit:                       1000.0
quotas[0].metric:                      SNAPSHOTS
quotas[0].usage:                       0.0
quotas[1].limit:                       5.0
quotas[1].metric:                      NETWORKS
quotas[1].usage:                       1.0
quotas[2].limit:                       100.0
quotas[2].metric:                      FIREWALLS
quotas[2].usage:                       9.0
quotas[3].limit:                       100.0
quotas[3].metric:                      IMAGES
quotas[3].usage:                       0.0
quotas[4].limit:                       8.0
quotas[4].metric:                      STATIC_ADDRESSES
quotas[4].usage:                       0.0
quotas[5].limit:                       200.0
quotas[5].metric:                      ROUTES
quotas[5].usage:                       1.0
quotas[6].limit:                       15.0
quotas[6].metric:                      FORWARDING_RULES
quotas[6].usage:                       0.0
quotas[7].limit:                       50.0
quotas[7].metric:                      TARGET_POOLS
quotas[7].usage:                       0.0
quotas[8].limit:                       50.0
quotas[8].metric:                      HEALTH_CHECKS
quotas[8].usage:                       0.0
quotas[9].limit:                       8.0
quotas[9].metric:                      IN_USE_ADDRESSES
quotas[9].usage:                       0.0
quotas[10].limit:                      50.0
quotas[10].metric:                     TARGET_INSTANCES
quotas[10].usage:                      0.0
quotas[11].limit:                      10.0
quotas[11].metric:                     TARGET_HTTP_PROXIES
quotas[11].usage:                      0.0
quotas[12].limit:                      10.0
quotas[12].metric:                     URL_MAPS
quotas[12].usage:                      0.0
quotas[13].limit:                      50.0
quotas[13].metric:                     BACKEND_SERVICES
quotas[13].usage:                      0.0
quotas[14].limit:                      100.0
quotas[14].metric:                     INSTANCE_TEMPLATES
quotas[14].usage:                      0.0
quotas[15].limit:                      5.0
quotas[15].metric:                     TARGET_VPN_GATEWAYS
quotas[15].usage:                      0.0
quotas[16].limit:                      10.0
quotas[16].metric:                     VPN_TUNNELS
quotas[16].usage:                      0.0
quotas[17].limit:                      3.0
quotas[17].metric:                     BACKEND_BUCKETS
quotas[17].usage:                      0.0
quotas[18].limit:                      10.0
quotas[18].metric:                     ROUTERS
quotas[18].usage:                      0.0
quotas[19].limit:                      10.0
quotas[19].metric:                     TARGET_SSL_PROXIES
quotas[19].usage:                      0.0
quotas[20].limit:                      10.0
quotas[20].metric:                     TARGET_HTTPS_PROXIES
quotas[20].usage:                      0.0
quotas[21].limit:                      10.0
quotas[21].metric:                     SSL_CERTIFICATES
quotas[21].usage:                      0.0
quotas[22].limit:                      100.0
quotas[22].metric:                     SUBNETWORKS
quotas[22].usage:                      0.0
quotas[23].limit:                      10.0
quotas[23].metric:                     TARGET_TCP_PROXIES
quotas[23].usage:                      0.0
quotas[24].limit:                      32.0
quotas[24].metric:                     CPUS_ALL_REGIONS
quotas[24].usage:                      1.0
quotas[25].limit:                      10.0
quotas[25].metric:                     SECURITY_POLICIES
quotas[25].usage:                      0.0
quotas[26].limit:                      100.0
quotas[26].metric:                     SECURITY_POLICY_RULES
quotas[26].usage:                      0.0
quotas[27].limit:                      1000.0
quotas[27].metric:                     XPN_SERVICE_PROJECTS
quotas[27].usage:                      0.0
quotas[28].limit:                      20.0
quotas[28].metric:                     PACKET_MIRRORINGS
quotas[28].usage:                      0.0
quotas[29].limit:                      100.0
quotas[29].metric:                     NETWORK_ENDPOINT_GROUPS
quotas[29].usage:                      0.0
quotas[30].limit:                      6.0
quotas[30].metric:                     INTERCONNECTS
quotas[30].usage:                      0.0
quotas[31].limit:                      5000.0
quotas[31].metric:                     GLOBAL_INTERNAL_ADDRESSES
quotas[31].usage:                      0.0
quotas[32].limit:                      5.0
quotas[32].metric:                     VPN_GATEWAYS
quotas[32].usage:                      0.0
quotas[33].limit:                      100.0
quotas[33].metric:                     MACHINE_IMAGES
quotas[33].usage:                      0.0
quotas[34].limit:                      20.0
quotas[34].metric:                     SECURITY_POLICY_CEVAL_RULES
quotas[34].usage:                      0.0
quotas[35].limit:                      0.0
quotas[35].metric:                     GPUS_ALL_REGIONS
quotas[35].usage:                      0.0
quotas[36].limit:                      5.0
quotas[36].metric:                     EXTERNAL_VPN_GATEWAYS
quotas[36].usage:                      0.0
quotas[37].limit:                      1.0
quotas[37].metric:                     PUBLIC_ADVERTISED_PREFIXES
quotas[37].usage:                      0.0
quotas[38].limit:                      10.0
quotas[38].metric:                     PUBLIC_DELEGATED_PREFIXES
quotas[38].usage:                      0.0
quotas[39].limit:                      128.0
quotas[39].metric:                     STATIC_BYOIP_ADDRESSES
quotas[39].usage:                      0.0
quotas[40].limit:                      10.0
quotas[40].metric:                     NETWORK_FIREWALL_POLICIES
quotas[40].usage:                      0.0
quotas[41].limit:                      15.0
quotas[41].metric:                     INTERNAL_TRAFFIC_DIRECTOR_FORWARDING_RULES
quotas[41].usage:                      0.0
quotas[42].limit:                      15.0
quotas[42].metric:                     GLOBAL_EXTERNAL_MANAGED_FORWARDING_RULES
quotas[42].usage:                      0.0
selfLink:                              https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/principal-storm-368908
vmDnsSetting:                          ZONAL_ONLY
xpnProjectStatus:                      UNSPECIFIED_XPN_PROJECT_STATUS
```

Comment: 1) Make sure the time zone and time are correct on your computer. 2) Run this command and save the output. What does the output show regarding ssh? `gcloud compute project-info describe --format flattened` Edit your question with those details. 3) Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#metadata

Comment: I have added a key in the metadata that looks like this: ssh-rsa ABCD.....XYZ google-ssh {""userName":"my_user_name@gmail.com","expireOn":"2023-12-04T17:04:46+0000""}. But still I see the ssh key expired error

Comment: You have added a new SSH key, now how are you using that key to connect? Edit your question with details and not in the comments. Too hard to read and check for errors.

Comment: Thanks John for the feedback..I will add the details in the comments in future. For now, the IP (http://34.135.68.155/) is running so I will try building my wordpress website on it :)

Answer (score 0):

From the error shared on your description the ssh key expired.

You need to create a new rsa key

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then copy the new public ssh key in the VM instance section *ssh key*.

Please! Copy the public key not the private, you can identify the public with the extension .pub

Follow the instruction from [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#ssh_troubleshooting_tool)